# Combining URL text box with FileUpload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I'm developing a web app which allows users to upload images.  Instead of forcing them to first download an image I also want to allow them to provide a URL of the image elsewhere on the web.

I've got the code to do this, my question is **how can I combine these into one text box** that will allow the user to enter *either* the location of the image on their hard drive *or* the location of the image on the web.

I'm aware of the ASP File Upload control - but how could I leverage it to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let them choose like you can here at StackOverflow? (try to add an image to an answer; you get the same option).

Comment: Yes I had a feeling that combining into the same box was possibly a bad idea. I'd never seen the upload on here - so I think I'll take this route